# Converting unbalanced panels into balanced/dropping multiple observations on single condition

Tags: statistics, missing-data, spss

There is a dataset with 3 variables - ***ID***, ***Wage*** and ***Year***, it is an unbalanced panel.There are 2 problems:

1. I want to drop *all* data on such ***IDs*** for which there is a ***Year*** with no observations. Shortly, i want to convert my unbalanced panel into balanced dropping every id that creates this "unbalanceness".

For example, if a guy with ***ID*** = 1 didn't report his ***Wage*** in a ***Year*** = 2010 (and therefore there is no observation with ***Year*** = 2010 and ***ID*** = 1), I want to drop all data for ***ID*** = 1.

It seems like a popular question, but all I found on Google and StackOverflow were multiple solutions for Stata and none for SPSS.

UPDATE: I managed to solve this problem using COUNTIF Excel function. I created a variabe that counted amount of times certain ***ID*** appeared in dataset and kept obseravtions for which this function=amount of years, thus dropping unbalanced ***IDs***. However, i'm still in dire need of solution to the second problem :)

2. Second question is almost the same as the first one - I want to drop *all* data on such ***IDs*** for which there is a ***Year*** when they reported ***Wage*** = 0

For example, if a guy with ***ID*** = 1 reported ***Wage*** = 0 in a ***Year*** = 2010, I want to drop all data for ***ID*** = 1.

If there is a filling command in SPSS that balances unbalanced panel with missing values, it seems like solution to second problem is a solution to the first one at the same time.

UPDATE 2: I solved this problem as well using COUNTIFS on ***Wage*** and ***ID***. Excel is omnipotent, praise Excel.

Comment: Why do all this dirty work in Excel when three simple lines of syntax will do everything automatically? For some jobs Excel may provide a better solution than SPSS, But this is definitely not one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve both tasks:

```
recode Wage (0=sysmis).
AGGREGATE /OUTFILE=* MODE=ADDVARIABLES /BREAK=ID /Wage_nmiss=NMISS(Wage).
select if Wage_nmiss=0.
execute.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the data is used for, but if it's something important, you should seriously reconsider deleting the observations with missing variables.

Often, especially in data on wages, a missing value tells you something about the value that should have been recorded (Link to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_data#Types_of_missing_data), Keywords: MAR, MCAR, MNAR)). There are no easy ways to get rid of this bias in your sample, but simply deleting the observation is not a serious option. There are algorithms that manage to cleverly impute missing values, based on the other values in the dataset.

If you'd like, I could invest a bit more time and help you find a suitable algorithm to impute the missing values..